# Modern OpenGL: should I use a custom matrix stack?

Tags: opengl, graphics, 3d, shader

Old fixed-pipeline OpenGL programming made heavy use of the matrix stack principle.

With flexible shaders I'm now free to create and use my own matrices as I like. I've read tutorials that don't seem to use any kind of matrix stack anymore, instead just saving and applying the necessary matrices as needed.

Others, like [this one](http://alfonse.bitbucket.org/oldtut/Positioning/Tutorial%2007.html), seem to use a matrix stack library for all of their matrices (see the example code in the linked chapter).

My question is: Is this a purely arbitrary preference, or is one or the other way preferred with modern graphics programming?

Comment: Not using stacks is preferred. In core profile there are no stacks upfront, and I strongly encourage you to use core profile for new projects. Store model matrix with your object and pass to shader as uniform along with view and projection matrices. The stacks were there so hierarchical calls were easier to perform.

Comment: @Mars I'm using the core profile, so I will definitely not be using the OpenGL stacks. But some tutorials use their own stacks or std::stack or something like that, where as others don't seem to be using stacks, just saving the matrices in appropriate classes/objects. Would you recommend to not use stacks for "normal" drawing and use your own stack implementation or library when you need hierachy (e.g. joints etc.)?

Comment: TL;DR: yes.
But it mostly depends on which approach you find more "natural" and are more comfortable with. One might be so influenced by old pipeline, cannot handle not having stack of matrices and thus must implement his own. Another person could not see anything valuable in the stack. I'm nearly the latter one. Worked with some 2.x OpenGL, then switched to 3.x. At first I implemented my own stack, but later I found it not so good for general purpose usage with programmable shaders. I am nowhere near professional OpenGL dev, just worked with some code through my (short) life.

Answer (score 1):

How you generate your matrix data is more or less irrelevant. In very high-performance scenarios, one solution might be preferred over another, but it would ultimately be very engine specific.

If you want to use the C++ stack to have a hierarchy of objects, so be it. If you want to have an explicit stack of matrices that you push/pop at will, have at it. If you want to do something else entirely, that's up to you.

There is no right answer; there is only what works best for you and your code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Do you know of any recommended practices? I'm very new to OpenGL, so I wouldn't really know "what works best for me". Since I'm writing completely new code anyway, I'm free to choose any method. But if one is generally regarded as the best way in most scenarios, then I'd just like to just use that one instead of trying all the methods and be wiser 5 years down the road :)